# Run Ansible role without running dependencies defined in the role's meta

Tags: ansible

I have a role `wp-vhost` that has one role it depends on:

```
// roles/wp-vhost/meta/main.yml
---
dependencies:
  - { role: nginx }
```

Each time I run `wp-vhost`, the `nginx` role will also run. I understand that this is fine and it's a desired behavior.

However, during my local development, time is unnecessarily lost on running the `nginx` role, when I want to run only the tasks defined in `wp-vhosts` since I know that `nginx` had run before and set-up the necessary environment for `wp-vhost`.

Is there a way to execute a playbook with roles, without executing roles' dependencies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I would do this is to use [Ansible tags](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_tags.html) and apply them to your "wp-vhost" specific code.

Assuming your `wp-vhost` role's main playbook is in `main.yml`, a good pattern is to spin out the actual tasks into a sub-playbook called something like `wp-vhost.yml`, included from main.yml, so the non-nginx code gets a tag that doesn't get applied to the nginx role.  In this case:

```
- include: wp-vhost.yml
  tags: wp-vhost
```

In order to use a tag for every chunk of Ansible code (whether an included tasks file or a role), try writing every role mentioned in `dependencies` like this:

```
- role: nginx
  tags: nginx
```

When in testing mode, you can run just the wp-vhost specific parts like this:

```
 $ ansible-playbook --tags wp-vhost main.yml
```

Or you can run the whole playbook including any dependencies like this - default is to run everything ignoring tags:

```
 $ ansible-playbook main.yml
```

This makes it easy to quickly run just parts of a complex set of cascading roles and include files when testing, and also use the wp-vhost role normally in other roles' dependencies.

**Impact on role structure**

Careful use of tags doesn't affect role structure or use at all, and you would typically use tags only for testing.

For more complex roles, it's common to structure the tasks into separate files in any case, keeping the main.yml simple, like this:

```
- name: Set up base OS
  include: base_os.yml
  tags: base_os

- name: Ensure logs are rotated
  include: logrotate.yml
  tags: logrotate

- name: Create users and groups
  include: users_groups.yml
  tags: users_groups
```

**Solution without include files**

If you don't want to change the wp-vhosts use of include files, you would need to use blocks in the playbook (Ansible 2.0+):

```
- hosts: all

  roles:
    - role: nginx
      tags: nginx

  tasks:
    - block:  
        - debug: msg=hello
        - someaction: ...
      tags: wp-vhosts
```

Note that the final `tags:` is aligned with the `block:` so applies to all tasks in that block.  This is cleaner than splitting the playbook into multiple plays.

**Non-tag alternative**

You can use a `when:` condition [on the role invocation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_conditionals.html#applying-when-to-roles-imports-and-includes) in the wp-vhost role dependencies, and define a variable such as `debug_mode` to control this.  However, such debug/test logic will clutter your codebase compared to defining a tag per role invocation or task file.

Comment: Hi @RichVel, isn't the above approach essentially equivalent to resigning from defining any dependencies for the `wp-vhost` role in the role's meta? If I turn `wp-vhost`role into a separate playbook with individual tasks, it stopped being a role that can be shared, imported, defined as a dependency, etc. My intention is to maintain `wp-vhost` and `nginx` as separate roles rather than separate playbooks/collections of included tasks. Perhaps, what I want to achieve (occasionally running a role without its dependencies) is not easily achievable with Ansible.. unless I got something wrong..

Comment: @luqo33 - if you don't specify any tags the role works "as designed" with nginx dependency.  You would normally specify tags only when you want a short-cut to run part of the role / tasks - the tags are completely optional and don't stop the role being used as a dependency.  I've updated the answer with an example at end.

Comment: Thanks again, I found that your approach allows me to run roles without its dependencies. However, there is one note to make that, mainly, if the main playbook lists roles and not tasks like so: `- {role: wp-vhosts, tags: [vhosts]}`, running the "vhosts" tag will ALWAYS run the roles dependencies because here, the tag applies to the whole role (and its dependencies). So the solution is to get rid of the tag in the main playbook file, and instead apply the tags to individual tasks in that role (preferably using proposed include statements). In consequence, there is impact on role structure.

Comment: That makes sense, given that a single play cascades its tags to the roles and tasks within it.  I've edited my answer to show how this can be done with blocks so only the tasks get the tag, without error-prone assignment of tags on every task.

Comment: My personal vote goes for heavy `when:` use. You just simply check is the nginx (even specific version) presented on the system, if it is, then that dependency will be skipped. If the version does not match, then the old one will be wiped and the new one installed. IMHO it's much more "strategic" approach.